# How to store a large Data to PostgreSQL DB all at once?

Tags: php, postgresql, codeigniter

My idea was to store this large data inside an array an store it to my database. But in my recent post here, i found out that it is not a good practice to store arrays in SQL databases. I have here a sample table:

[image: Sample Table 1.0]

What i did was:

```
                $test = array
                (
                array($name[0],$age[0],$bday[0]),
                array($name[1],$age[1],$bday[1]),
                array($name[2],$age[2],$bday[2])
                );
```

Note: My original table is way too large and is completely in different scale. But i think it has the same way in storing it to DB. Im using MVC CodeIgniter (PHP, PostgreSQL DB). I really  need this. I need Help.

Comment: Two birthdays doesn't exactly qualify as "large data". Can you explain this in more detail?

Comment: have you read my note? this is just a sample data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into how database export looks like and let yourself inspire with it. Basically you want to build one INSERT statement containing as much data as possible and send it into db. Based on database timeouts and other variables you may need to split it into smaller ones.